# pfsense setting up as transparent firewall - dhcp issue

Tags: firewall, dhcp, bridge, pfsense

I followed the directions to set up pfsense in bridged / transparent mode per the instructions at http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Configuring_pfSense

However I can not get a dhcp address from my internet router.

It works fine if I set my machine to a static address - I have internet connectivity.

But if I set to dhcp, I never get an address.  I can get an address fine if I plug directly in to the WAN side of the network.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean your router is not giving your desktop a DHCP lease, or that your pfSense box is not getting an IP address? When you "plug in to the WAN side" do you mean you plug your desktop computer into your modem? Can you please clarify? Remember, when you're using bridge mode the pfsense box will not have an IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of DHCP is broadcast traffic.

Relevant excerpt from pfsense forums: http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=13351.0

> Since around 1.2.1-RC1 when you bridge an interface, pfSense (correctly, but silently) blocks broadcast traffic between the interfaces.

Firewall rule recommended to add:

UDP      *      67 - 68      *      67 - 68      *             pass dhcp traffic

You may also have issues with UPNP and other broadcast traffic if your use is across the bridge. (Print server or network shared drive on router.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to a DHCP server on the WAN side, you're probably blocking DHCP traffic. Check your firewall logs.