# pfSense - DHCP Relay

Tags: dhcp, pfsense

I have 3 pfSense boxes acting as routers on a single subnet (172.22.12.0/26).

- Router A - 172.22.12.1
- Router B - 172.22.12.17
- Router C - 172.22.12.33

I want Router A to be the only DHCP server. Router C has DHCP relay enabled that points to Router B. Router B then has DHCP relay enabled that points to Router A. Like this:

**Router C --> Router B --> Router A (DHCP Server)**

Router B gets an IP from Router A, but Router C does not. Any ideas why this configuration isn't working? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this post perhaps: [Answer by Joe](https://serverfault.com/a/275105)

> Firewall rule recommended to add:
>
> UDP * 67 - 68 * 67 - 68 * pass dhcp traffic